# Can I know my router's external IP address without visiting a website?

Tags: networking, router, ip

I want to know what my router's external IP address is. The only solution I have found is to visit a website like https://www.whatismyip.com/

But I don't understand why this IP address can't be obtained by just logging into my router (http://192.168.1.1) and get it from there, doesn't the router knows its own IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Your router should know its own external IP address, mine does, and if I log in to the status page I can read it.

software can read it too: eg, I use the following in my `/etc/ddclient.conf`

```
use=web, web='http://192.168.2.1/status_main.stm', web-skip='var wan_ip="'
```

Which lets the `ddclient` software get the external IP address from that page on my router.  Your router will probably be different in detail but it likely similar in general operation.

The convenient thing about websites like http://icanhazip.com is that they work for everyone, there no need to find the router and the password to log into it to read the connection parameters.

upnp is another way to do this, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799557/trying-to-get-nats-external-ipaddress-with-inatexternalipaddresscallback-in-c-s

Comment: You can also simply ask Google - search 'what's my IP address' & it will tell you, along with a list of sites that would also report it to you.